# Getting the Device Token when tapping the "Don't Allow" button for Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have a bit of difficulty getting the device token when the user tapped the "Don't Allow" Button.

*I can only get the Device Token when tapping the "OK" button. -- i have no problem with this one*

**Here is the note from the UIApplication.h**

```
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

> // Calling this will result in either
>   application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: or
>   application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: to be
>   called on the application delegate.
>
> Note: these callbacks will be made only if the application has
>   successfully registered for user notifications with
>   registerUserNotificationSettings:, or if it is enabled for Background
>   App Refresh.

? does this note means that if you select the "Don't Allow" button you can never get the device token ?

Comment: Why would you need it if the user is declining notifications?

Comment: You should attempt to register for notifications each time your app launches.  If the user subsequently allows notifications for your app through settings then you will get a a call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications`

Comment: As per `Apple guideline` of `APNS` if your app enable with `APNS` service and its upon to user that he/she wants to allow to enable Notification or not if user don't wants to allow than you can not get `Token` and if user wants to allow in future he/she wants to enable that from Settings.

Ref Link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: When using iOS 7 (and pre-iOS 4) you won't get the device token when you decline on the push dialog. With iOS 5, 6, 8, 9 you should get the device token regardless of whether you accept or decline the push dialog. See https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/how-ios-7-handles-push-differently

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on the user's action to receive the Device Token.

If you included in your app:

```
 - (void)application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

You still can get the device token even if the user disables it

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter, what action you choose in the permission popup for Push Notifications, the device token will anyways be obtained everytime and the only difference that user choice makes is that, it enables/disables the notification in the phone Settings.

And this behaviour is ideal. For an example:-

When user clicks on Dont Allow, if no device token is fetched and later on if user turn on the notification from the phone settings , then how are you going to send the deivice token to the server?
You will have to register for remote notification once again which is very weird.

I hope you understood.